# about conductor theorem

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

I'm looking for a "simple" proof of the fact
that all ramified primes divides the conductor of an extension.

By "simple" i mean a proof which DOES'NT use local Artin map, norm
residue symbol etc (as in Bochéat-Mischler, Janusz, Neukirsch)
I don't need deeper results for example about the exponents; just the
fact that ramified primes divides the conductors.

I would be very astonished if this result wasn't well known before Artin.